# Eliminate certain duplicated rows after group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates, distinct

With this db:

> Chef(*cid*,cname,age),
>
> Recipe(*rid*,rname),
>
> Cooked(*orderid*,cid,rid,price)
>
> Customers(*cuid*,*orderid*,*time*,daytime,age)

[cid means **c**hef **id**, and so on]

Given orders from customers, I need to find for each chef, the difference between his age and the average of people who ordered his/her meals.
I wrote the following query:

```
select cid, Ch.age - AVG(Cu.age) as Diff
from Chef Ch NATURAL JOIN Cooked Co,Customers Cu
where Co.orderid = Cu.orderid
group by cid
```

This solves the problem, but if you assume that customers has their unique id, it might not work,because then one can order two meals of the same chef and affect the calculation.

Now I know it can be answered with NOT EXISTS but I'm looking for a soultion which includes the group by function (something similar to what I wrote). So far I couldn't find (I searched and tried many ways, from select distinct , to manipulation in the where clause ,to "having count(distinct..)"  )

Edit: People asked for an exmaple. i'm coding using SQLFiddle and it crashes alot, so I'll try my best:

```
cid | cuid | orderid | Cu.age
-----------------------------
1    333    1         20
1    200    2         41
1    200    5         41
2    4      3         36
```

Let's say Chef 1's age is 50 . My query will give you 50 - (20+40+40/3) = 16 and 2/3. althought it should actually be 50 - (20+40/2) = 20. (because the guy with id 200 ordered two recipes of our beloved Chef 1.). 
Assume Chef 2's age is 47. My query will result:

```
cid | Diff
----------
1    16.667
2    11
```

Another edit: I wasn't taught any particular sql-query form.So I really have no idea what are the differences between Oracle's to MySql's to Microsoft Server's, so I'm basically "freestyle" querying.(I hope it will be good in my exam as well :O )

Comment: Showing us sample data would be very helpful, because it would allow us to easily see the problem with your data.

Comment: That's invalid SQL according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, in several aspects... However, the general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I.e. in your case I'd try `group by cid, ch.age`

Comment: MySQL allows the syntax that he has, and because the age is going to be tied to the id it won't actually affect the results to do it that way. You are correct that it won't be ANSI standard though.

Comment: Looking more closely at the structure, having an orderid in the Customers table makes no sense to me. As @Tim suggested, some sample data would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should write your query as:

```
select cid, Ch.age - AVG(Cu.age) as Diff
from Chef Ch join
     Cooked Co
     on ch.cid = co.cid join
     Customers Cu
     on Co.orderid = Cu.orderid
group by cid;
```

Two different reasons:

- `NATURAL JOIN` is just a bug waiting to happen.  List the columns that you want used for the join, lest an unexpected field or spelling difference affect the results.
- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Next, the answer to your question is more complicated.  For each chef, we can get the average age of the customers by doing:

```
select cid, avg(age) 
from (select distinct co.cid, cu.cuid, cu.age
      from Cooked Co join
           Customers Cu
           on Co.orderid = Cu.orderid
     ) c
group by cid;
```

Then, for the difference, you need to bring that information in as well.  One method is in the subquery:

```
select cid, ( age - avg(cuage) ) as diff
from (select distinct co.cid, cu.cuid, cu.age as cuage, c.age as cage
      from Chef c join
           Cooked Co
           on ch.cid = co.cid join
           Customers Cu
           on Co.orderid = Cu.orderid
     ) c
group by cid, cage;
```